# Spliting Single Column Query values to different php variables

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, codeigniter-3

need some help with splitting mysql single column query array into different php variables here.

example:

here's the query, it's pretty simple to be honest.
but, i'm running out of ideas right now.

```
$string = "select Description from tblQuestion
    where Employeeid = '$param'"
    $query = $this->db->query($string);
    $result = return $query->result_array();
```

btw, i am using Codeigniter and i tried to var_dump and the results are like this.

```
array(9) { [0]=> array(1) { ["Description"]=> string(5) "tidak" } [1]=> array(1) { ["Description"]=> string(5) "tidak" } [2]=> array(1) { ["Description"]=> string(5) "tidak" } [3]=> array(1) { ["Description"]=> string(5) "tidak" } [4]=> array(1) { ["Description"]=> string(5) "tidak" } [5]=> array(1) { ["Description"]=> string(5) "tidak" } [6]=> array(1) { ["Description"]=> string(5) "tidak" } [7]=> array(1) { ["Description"]=> string(5) "tidak" } [8]=> array(1) { ["Description"]=> string(5) "tidak" } }
```

i tried to use json_encode and the result is

```
[{"Description":"tidak"},{"Description":"tidak"},{"Description":"tidak"},{"Description":"tidak"},{"Description":"tidak"},{"Description":"tidak"},{"Description":"tidak"},{"Description":"tidak"},{"Description":"tidak"}]
```

the question is.

how do i convert this stack of arrays into different variables like this?

```
$var0 = "tidak";
$var1 = "tidak";
$var2 = "tidak";
$var3 = "tidak";
```

and on and on....

thanks in advance.

cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Put the results in a foreach loop and assign the values to a dynamic variable...

sample code like,

```
foreach($results as $key=>$val){
    $str = 'var'.$key;
    $$str = $val['Description'];
}
echo $var0;
```

Comment: is it possible to use Json?

Comment: use `json_encode` function to convert a PHP array to json format.

Comment: You have to reverse the json to array using `json_decode` function and process the array using foreach statement as said in the answer.